# I can't see the information of a movie when I click on it

Tags: reactjs

I would like to see the information of the movie when I click on it but it only shows me the information of the popular movies and not the ones I search by input. In other words, in the URL I see that I am inside them but it doesn't show me anything.

I have been trying things for a whole day and nothing works.

useHomeFetch.js

```
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [searchMovie, setSearchMovie] = useState('');

  const getPopular = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(POPULAR);
    const data = await res.json();
    setMovies(data.results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPopular();
  }, []);

  const getSearch = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(SEARCH + searchMovie);
    const data = await res.json();

    if (data.results) {
      setMovies(data.results);
    } else {
      getPopular();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getSearch(searchMovie);
  }, [searchMovie]);

  return { movies, searchMovie, setSearchMovie };
};
```

Home.js

```
  const mov = useHomeFetch();

  return (
    <div>
      <Search searchMovie={mov.searchMovie} setSearchMovie={mov.setSearchMovie}/>
      <div className="movie--container">
        {mov.movies.map((movie) => (
          <Link to={'/' + movie.id}>
            <div className="image-container" key={movie.id}>
              <img
                className="movie--poster"
                src={movie.poster_path === null ? NoImage : IMAGE + movie.poster_path}
                alt={movie.title}
              />
              <h3 className="title">{movie.title}</h3>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

MovieInfo.js

```
const MovieInfo = () => {
  const mov = useHomeFetch();
  const params = useParams();

  const infoMovie = mov.movies.find((movie) => movie.id === parseInt(params.movieId));

  let info= '';

  if (infoMovie) {
    info = infoMovie.overview;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{info}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like the issue is to do with your `MovieInfo.js` file. You need to utilise the hooks like `useEffect` to handle data rather than inside the body of the component. This is just causing unnecessary re-renders whenever something changes.

You also need to include something that renders when you are trying to find a movie as it might not be as fast as you want it to be. In my example I have included a loading string which you only see once you have found a movie.

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const MovieInfo = () => {
  const mov = useHomeFetch();
  const params = useParams();
  const [info, setInfo] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const infoMovie = mov.movies.find((movie) => movie.id === parseInt(params.movieId));
    if(infoMovie) {
      setInfo(infoMovie);
    }
  }, [mov, params.movieId])

  if(!info) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{info}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieInfo;
```

PS. I think you might be over complicating your app with having everything in the `useHomeFetch` hook and you should go look at how the lifecycle of a react component works again so you are only rendering when you need it to.